# How to get system icons in iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios, icons

I want to use icons like opened/closed folder in my table (UITableView)?

UPD:
For example, in Java you can get a standard image "folder" and use it in the FileTree:

> new
>   DefaultTreeCellRenderer().getDefaultClosedIcon()

And also can use the constants of L&F (colors, styles, icons).

In the iOS, I found only these [standard icons](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/UIElementGuidelines/UIElementGuidelines.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH13-SW30).
But not folder icons...

Comment: Where in iOS do you see folder icons? **There are no standard folder icons because there are no folders.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not quite sure exactly what you want - the folder icon from iOS? Could you explain a little better?

If it is a folder icon that you want, there's no quick way to get it from code - doing so would use private API's and your app is likely to be rejected from the app store.

If you want something like a folder icon, a good way to get it would be by taking a screenshot of the iPhone simulator and editing it to the right size etc.

Comment: There are many programs that have the same image: http://origin.arstechnica.com/reviews/os/mac-os-x-10-5.media/leopard-folder.png

Comment: These are OSX folders, not iOS folders... if you want to use it as an image in your app, just copy and paste it from the above link.